# Javascript iteration count array instances in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, syntax, iterator

I feel like there are a lot of questions similar to this here, but as I am still stuck I guess I will ask.  This is a codecademy linter problem, and I cannot collect the number of instances that one array's elements are found in another.

Even with solutions provided by others in Git, I cant make 'my own' answer.  I have seen a lot of similar solutions here in S.O. but still not moving on.

array 1

```
[ a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a,...]
```

array 2

```
[a, b]
```

Code

```
const newConstant = (array1.forEach(foo) => {
     array2.filter (bar) => {
         if (foo[i] === bar[i]) {
             newConstant++;
         }
     }
});
```

I am probably bastardizing the solutions I have seen and taking the worst of both worlds.  But as I have looked at this for nearly 2 hours in 3 sessions I am just getting cross-eyed. Why cant I collect the number of times a and b appear in array 1?

error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token'

Comment: Well-intentioned advice: throw that piece of script in the trash, check how arrow functions work, what `.forEach()` and `.filter()` do and return, what the `const` keyword does and how indices work.

Comment: According to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp and same with foreach, they both expect functions, not names like foo and bar; and where did you get the i index from??

Comment: Man, no offense meant, but you must first understand that you cannot type everything and anything in any order. You have a syntax to respect. That's why you get `SyntaxError`. Check that every `([{` has its own `)]}`.
Please present readable and runnable code.

Comment: I have just learned those iterations .forEach and .filter. I am trying to use them now.  So telling me to scrap everything and go learn something isnt helpful.  Also, this code is as readable as I can make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code...

I believe you should read up on variable declaration and arrow functions, because as the error stated, your syntax is not correct.

Here is your piece modified to have the desired function:

```
let newConstant = 0;
array1.forEach((foo) => {
    array2.filter((bar) => {
        if (foo === bar) {
            newConstant++;
        }
    })
});
console.log(newConstant);
```

However, I would approach it differently, such as:

```
let count=0;
array1.map((elm1) => {
    if(array2.indexOf(elm1)!==-1) {
        count+=1;
    }
});
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I made 3 errors: 1.  I declared my new variable incorrectly as a constant when I needed to increment it.  2. I missed a set of soft brackets to embed the foo and bar arguments within the array filter.  3. I needlessly added square brackets to foo and bar.    I have used up my upvotes for today I will get you tomorrow.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have major syntax errors, Here is the correction of the syntax:

```
let newConstant = 0;
array1.forEach( foo => {
    array2.filter( bar => {
        if( foo === bar ){
            newConstant++;
        }
    } )

} );
```

You can't `const` cause you are incrementing the value of the variable (reassigning the value), And this keyword `const` means that you want to give it an initial value and never change it.
So replace it with `let`, which allows to change the value of the variable.

The 2 methods `forEach` & `filter` takes as the argument a function, On this code you are using the arrow function `foo => { ... }`, but with wrong syntax.

So you need to pass this function as the argument of `forEach` & `filter` by puting the whole between the parentheses of `forEach( HERE! )`... Ex: `array1.forEach( foo => { ... } )`

The last thing i see you that you was trying to increment `newConstant` when declaring &  assigning to that variable, which is not possible or at least it won't work.

Comment: Don't make the same mistake as OP. Don't abuse `Array#filter` as `Array#forEach`

Comment: doh, the const advice seems true, i was doomed to failure here as i was never going to let this go on my own...

Comment: @Thomas i left `Array#filter` as it is to not confuse "Darryl Calder" who posted the question, because i already changed his code and explaned why and what i did, Just corrected the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already gotten some answers I thought I would provide an alternative. This might be a little slower than some other answers but I like the way it reads.

```js
var findNeedles = function (needle, haystack) {
  return haystack
    // we only need to check as far as there is room for the needle
    .slice(0, haystack.length - needle.length + 1)
    // get each subsection that may match the needle (same length)
    .map((c, i, a) => haystack.slice(i, i + needle.length))
    // filter out sections that match the needle
    .filter(c => c.every((e, i)=> e === needle[i] ));
}

var haystack = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a"];
var needle = ["a", "b"];
console.log("Found matches: ", findNeedles(needle, haystack).length);
```

You can also break things down more to make it more readable if you aren't sure. For example

```js
var findNeedles = function (needle, haystack) {
  var getPotentialNeedle = (c, i, a) => haystack.slice(i, i + needle.length);
  
  var needlePartMatches = (part, index) => part === needle[index];
  
  var isNeedle = (potentialNeedle) => potentialNeedle.every(needlePartMatches);
  
  return haystack
    // we only need to check as far as there is room for the needle
    .slice(0, haystack.length - needle.length + 1)
    .map(getPotentialNeedle)
    .filter(isNeedle);
}

var haystack = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a"];
var needle = ["a", "b"];
console.log("Found matches: ", findNeedles(needle, haystack).length);
```

Comment: Thank you, slice and map are also iterations I have just touched on in the past couple of days.  I am still struggling with the syntax and order of operations of javascript in general.

Comment: As a quick explanation `slice` just returns a sub array from index x to y. `map` takes a [lambda/arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), loops over every item, and passes the item (c), the index (i), and the array (a) and then builds a new array based on the return values. Lambda functions are pretty easy. They are just parameters, =>, and a return value. In my example I am returning another slice starting at index and going to index + needle length for the first map and a boolean check for filter.

Comment: thank you, these iterations their own they dont seem that complicated during the lesson but when there are multiple )]}; requirements in one function i get confused.   :-/   At some point soon I need to take a step back and improve my glossary.

Comment: Just some friendly advice, keep learning because you will need to understand how to read/write syntax but try to avoid code like that. You can always tweak code and break parts out to make it more readable. I added another example. It does the same thing but uses less nesting. I created three variable functions with nice, readable names and you dont have any chained braces anymore. Don't be afraid to write longer code if it helps you read it better, a lot of people think short === good!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution,

```
var array1  = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a'];

var array2 =  ['a', 'b', 'a'];

var result = {};

array2.forEach((elem) => {
    let count = array1.filter(element => element === elem);
    result[Symbol('a')] = count.length; // Here we use symbols to catch hold of repeated elements
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution ;)

```
let arr1 =  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'b'];
let arr2 = ['a', 'b'];
let obj= {};
arr1.forEach(x => {
        arr2.forEach(y => {
            if(y === x){
                if(obj[x]){
                obj[x] = obj[x] + 1;
            } else {
                obj[x] = 1;
            }
        }
    });
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: TO is obviously a beginner. Throwing just a bunch of code at him won't help in the long-run. Add some explanation why his solution doesn't work and what you've changed and why.